# Handler.post cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, multithreading, eclipse, handler

I want to return value from a Thread, so the only possible way I found was to make a Handler:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() 
        {
new Handler.post(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                //code I want;
            }}

}});
```

but I receive Handler.post cannot be resolved to a type ( Fix project setup) on Eclipse.
Please any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other best solutions available but to provide a simple solution, I just modified your code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("MyLog", "Thread....");
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("MyLog", "Handler....");
                    // Code you want goes here....
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: it was helping to remember me of the .start() I totaly forgot it in my code and was wondering for 3 days what was really wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is a new and easy way for Multithreading: https://medium.com/gradeup/simplest-rxjava-tutorial-for-android-262013ce3545

Comment: I hope if there is an other sample way.

Comment: one other way is EventBus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
The second is using Futures in java: https://www.journaldev.com/1650/java-futuretask-example-program.

Are you using this for Android Project or Java Project???

Comment: for Android Project

Comment: and I use Eclipse